Accessing KOHA website by domain name is slow compared to IP Address
I have a website http://librarydoa.online. When hitting the website through domain name it takes a considerably more amount of time compared when accessing the website through ip adddress ip. The site is running apache2 webserver and i have setup letsencrypt certificate.
.
